# how to set prefix to GeneratedDatabaseHolder.java class in dbflow in android studio 3

Tags: java, android, dbflow

in android studio 2.3.3 when useing dbflow in a module you can add a prefix to GeneratedDatabaseHolder class like this

```
apt {
     arguments {
          targetModuleName 'PreFixTitle'
     }
}
```

but in android studio 3 we cannot use apt right so how can I add prefix to that class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this problem today!
I solve this problem in this way:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
        android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [ targetModuleName : 'Ship' ]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

my project Build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } 
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
}
```

my [demo](https://github.com/DthFish/DBFlowDemo)